# Bi-direction port connection with signal in SystemC

Tags: systemc

In module hierarchy, on connecting inout port with sc_signal it shows error, So is there any other type of signal I  need to connect with inout (bidirectional port) ?

Error: (E115) sc_signal cannot have more than one driver: 
 signal `Dha.signal_0' (sc_signal)
 first driver`Dha.Memory.port_4'  (sc_inout)
 second driver `Dha.Alloc.port_3' (sc_inout)

Comment: Can you please provide more code/details, how you want to use the signal between two modules/processes?  How/when are the processes writing to the signal?

Comment: This is the code on which I'm working. Can you please guide me what is the mistake I'm doing.  https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3aQC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `sc_signal` with a writer policy of `SC_MANY_WRITERS` to drive a signal from multiple ports/processes.

```cpp
#include <systemc.h>
SC_MODULE(Foo) {
  sc_inout<bool> port;
  SC_CTOR(Foo)
    : port("port")
  {}
  // ...
};
SC_MODULE(Bar) {
  sc_inout<bool> port;
  SC_CTOR(Bar)
    : port("port")
  {}
  // ...
};
int sc_main(int, char*[])
{
  sc_signal<bool, SC_MANY_WRITERS> signal; // <-- policy here
  Foo foo("foo");
  Bar bar("bar");
  foo.port(signal);
  bar.port(signal);
  sc_start();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it gives another error. Error: (E115) sc_signal<T> cannot have more than one driver: 
 signal `Mila.signal_0' (sc_signal)
 first driver `Mila.Alloc.function'  (sc_method_process)
 second driver `Mila.Memory.read_mem' (sc_method_process)
 first conflicting write in delta cycle 6
In file: ../../../../src/sysc/communication/sc_signal.cpp:73
In process: Mila.Memory.read_mem @ 3 ns

Comment: You cannot write to the signal in the *same* delta cycle.  Which value should be taken in such a case? Synchronize your modules to drive the signal from one process only at every point in time.

Comment: Can you elaborate what delta cycle is?

Comment: This is a basic concept in SystemC. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850253/

Answer (score 0):

You need sc_signal_rv. Check example here http://www.asic-world.com/systemc/ports_signals4.html#Example_:_Resolved_Vector_Signals

Comment: I tried but it is not working. It is showing error. Is there any example you know where bi-directional port is being used with signal.